# Is there a simple Java framework for Image Processing?

Tags: java, image-processing, frameworks

I need to obtain a matrix with the pixels of an image and to manipulate it. Is there any framework or library for this written in/for Java?

Or is there a functionality in JDK for this?

Comment: Apparently @David, SO is a personal research assistant !  See below.

Comment: I have asked somewhere else and received an answer. Buffered Image has getRGB(int x, int y) and setRGB(int x, int y, int color).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I stand corrected. Apparently have a site full of poor questions is fine as long as you can harvest some rep from it.

Comment: @David: I'm in agreement with you that this question should be downvoted - and I did.  I did know how to point him in the right direction however - and unless he was going to delete the question, the clutter was here to stay (whether it went unanswered or not).

Comment: @GregKopff That's a fair point. I flagged for attention, but you're right. If the question stays at least it can have a good answer, and yours is of good quality.

Answer (score 3):

[BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

> The BufferedImage subclass describes an Image with an accessible buffer of image data. A BufferedImage is comprised of a ColorModel and a Raster of image data. The number and types of bands in the SampleModel of the Raster must match the number and types required by the ColorModel to represent its color and alpha components.

[Raster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html):

> A class representing a rectangular array of pixels. A Raster encapsulates a DataBuffer that stores the sample values and a SampleModel that describes how to locate a given sample value in a DataBuffer.

[ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

> A class containing static convenience methods for locating ImageReaders and ImageWriters, and performing simple encoding and decoding